# Query returns wrong row

Tags: sql-server, string, date, where-clause

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    [tblticket].[TicketID], 
    [Tblcustomers].[CustomerAccNo], 
    [tblticket].[TicketDate], [tblticket].[Collectdate], 
    [tblticket].[TicketTotal], [tblticket].[UserAccNo], 
    [Tblcustomers].[FirstName], [Tblcustomers].[Surname] 
FROM
    TbLTicket 
INNER JOIN 
    Tblcustomers ON TblTicket.[CustomerAccNo] = Tblcustomers.[CustomerAccNo] 
WHERE 
    TicketDate  BETWEEN '13/07/2020' and '24/07/2020'
```

When I run this query between the following dates as seen in the query, I get results with ticket dates that are 13/09/2019 included, please what am I doing wrong.

Please why are 13/09/2019 rows being included?

Comment: I think you need to CONVERT/CAST your date range values first.

Comment: Your `TicketDate` column is  a varchar.

Answer (score 1):

> why are 13/09/2019 rows being included?

You are doing string comparisons while you want date comparison.

If `TicketDate` is of a date-like datatype (as it should be) then consider using an unambiguous date format for the literals:

```
TicketDate between '20200713' and '20200724'
```

Else you need to `cast` it first. SQL Server is quite good at interpreting date formats, so this might be sufficient:

```
cast(TicketDate as date) between '20200713' and '20200724'
```

The last resort is to rebuild the date with `datefromparts()`. Assuming string format `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
datefromparts(
    substring(TicketDate, 7, 4),
    substring(TicketDate, 4, 2),
    substring(TicketDate, 1, 2)
) between '20200713' and '20200724'
```

Comment: Edit your answer please `'substr' is not a recognized built-in function name.` You mean `SUBSTRING()`

Comment: @Ilyes: thanks. The name of the function changes across databases so I get lost sometimes.